# Are deep learning models way over the required capacity for their datasets' estimated entropies?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, information-theory

this question might seem a bit odd. I was doing some self-studies into information theory and decided to do some more formal investigations into deep learning. Please bear with me as I try to explain.
I took a large "training" subset of MNIST as my guinea pig.

1) Converted every image in MNIST into "black-and-white" (pixels values only 0 or 1)

2) Summed over all data images to build a histogram over the pixels - I counted the number of times each pixel gets a 1 value in the dataset

3) Normalized histogram to get an estimate of the "true" probability distribution

4) From this, I got the following probability distribution (shown as a heatmap with matplotlib):

[[image: Probability distribution for an MNIST training set[1]]

5) Now I calculated the entropy and got: $191$ bits

6) According to David MacKay in his Information Theory book, we could interpret a neural network as a noisy channel and consider each neuron as having a 2 bit capacity. Although he does state to use this idea with care. Chapter 40 of his book http://www.inference.org.uk/itila/book.html)

7) So, as a rough estimate (and with care) we could say we would need a neural network of 95 neurons in order to be able to encode the labeling of this MNIST training set (190/2)
8) Now we can get to my question:

Even if this is a very "back-of-the-envelope" calculation, shouldn't a neural network capable of learning the labelling be at least in the ballpark of 95 neurons?
Why do we need, for instance, a neural network with 21840 parameters to get 99% accuracy? (considering the one in PyTorch's example for MNIST: https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py)

Answer (score 5):

The current thinking is that it is easier to fit an overparameterized neural network, since the local extrema are different ways of expressing the same thing, whereas in a minimal neural network you have to worry about getting to the global extremum:

> The subtle reason behind this is that smaller networks are harder to
>   train with local methods such as Gradient Descent: It’s clear that
>   their loss functions have relatively few local minima, but it turns
>   out that many of these minima are easier to converge to, and that they
>   are bad (i.e. with high loss). Conversely, bigger neural networks
>   contain significantly more local minima, but these minima turn out to
>   be much better in terms of their actual loss. Since Neural Networks
>   are non-convex, it is hard to study these properties mathematically,
>   but some attempts to understand these objective functions have been
>   made, e.g. in a recent paper The Loss Surfaces of Multilayer Networks.
>   In practice, what you find is that if you train a small network the
>   final loss can display a good amount of variance - in some cases you
>   get lucky and converge to a good place but in some cases you get
>   trapped in one of the bad minima. On the other hand, if you train a
>   large network you’ll start to find many different solutions, but the
>   variance in the final achieved loss will be much smaller. In other
>   words, all solutions are about equally as good, and rely less on the
>   luck of random initialization.

[CS231n Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Emre. Do you know of any study relating the entropy of datasets to the required network to achieve a given accuracy?
I am imagining here a plot, where X is entropy of a dataset and Y is the size in bits of the minimum network found so far that achieves 99% accuracy on it.

Comment: Not exactly, but [Tishby's information bottleneck method](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/labs/learning/Papers/IBM_list.html) and follow-ups such as [On the Information Bottleneck Theory of Deep Learning](https://openreview.net/forum?id=ry_WPG-A-) get pretty close and are rather interesting. There are also numerous papers on neural network compression, but the ones I can think of are empirical rather than theoretical like the aforementioned.